# Empty page in the attributes manager

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes

Not for sure but may be this is a noob Question.
If i want to change anything to the attributes sets in the attributes manager I get an empty page.

I tried to search in the log file and there is an error.

```
2014-08-23T11:34:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Grid/Abstract.php'
```

And I do not know how to fix this!
Any tips or tricks for this one?

Thank you,

Comment: Is the file at the server and is it readable?

Comment: Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute.... until this all is on the server but not the grid/abstract.php part. in the attribute file is a file edit/main/abstract.php .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the same version of Magento you are having right now from magento connect and find and upload the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Grid/Abstract.php
```

from it to your Magento install. It seems the file was either deleted or was not uploaded.